# Do something when other party answer the call and close the call

Tags: java, android, call

I use this code to call :

```
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel://0000");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,callUri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

i would like to do something when:

- other party answer the call
- other party close the call
- user close the call
- user close the call before other party answer the call

and how to close the call

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **TelephonyManager** to handle calls. Take a look at the following class...

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean phoneInACall = false;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // THE PHONE IS CURRENTLY RINGING!
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // THE PHONE IS ACTIVE, DIALING OR ON HOLD!
                phoneInACall = true;
            }
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // IDLE - NO ACTIVITY. IF PHONEINACALL WAS TRUE, IT MEANS THE CALL ENDED
                if (phoneInACall) {
                    // RESTART YOUR MAIN ACTIVITY BECAUSE A CALL ENDED!
                    phoneCalling = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

You can use this class in your **onCreate** method by creating an instance of this **PhoneStateListener** and getting an instance of a **TelephonyManager** to call the **listen** method to listen to receive notification of changes in specified telephony states...

```
PhoneCallListener phoneCallListener = new PhoneCallListener();
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telManager.listen(phoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

This code should help you solve your problems :) Good Luck!